# Deadline for moving iOS apps to ARC from Non-ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Apple announced that mac apps that are submitted to appstore from May 1, 2015 must be ARC enabled. Is there any deadline for iOS apps to move to ARC from non-ARC??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has never been any official date for iOS Apps not supporting `Garbage Collection`. They have only given the official date for Mac Apps not supporting `Garage Collection` which will be `May 1st 2015`, though I would probably say Apple will say in the next release of iOS that `Garbage Collection` will be officially dropped. I'd keep an eye on the `xcode IDE` release notes as they previously stated in the [`xcode 5` release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc5_release_notes.html) that it will be the final version to support `Garbage Collection` for Mac Apps

> **Garbage Collection Support**
>
> Xcode 5 ending support for OS X garbage collection.
>
> Garbage collection is a deprecated technology in OS X Mountain Lion and later. Xcode 5 is scheduled to be the last release of the Xcode developer tools to support building, debugging, or profiling Mac apps that use garbage collection. It is recommended that any projects using GC employ the Xcode migration tool to convert to ARC (Automatic Reference Counting.)

And on February 20th 2015 Apple gave an official date of `May 1st 2015` in the a little [news release](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02202015a)

> Beginning May 1, 2015, new Mac apps and app updates submitted to the Mac App Store may no longer use garbage collection, which was deprecated in OS X Mountain Lion. Instead, migrate your apps to Automatic Reference Counting, using the migration assistant in Xcode to help with this transition. Apps may continue to use retain/release for manual memory management.

So my recommendation would be to keep an eye on the `xcode` release notes and the [news](https://developer.apple.com/news/) section of the Apple Developer website to see if they release anything official over the next couple of months.

I had a good search online and couldn't find anything that relates to iOS not supporting `Garbage Collection` any more, though that doesn't mean it does support `Garbage Collection` still. Apple have been known to just doing things and not document it. In all honesty I'd say just make your apps using ARC now any way as it's easier and why would you want to do it twice? If I see anything in regards to this I will add it.

Answer (score 2):

In mac, garbage collection is deprecated and no longer available for apps uploading from May 1st 2015. But in iOS, there is no garbage collection available.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look. Thank you for your response

Comment: I think, currently Apple didn't announce any deadline for non-ARC code.